# The name 'GroupforA' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      List<Item> cont1 = new List<Item>();
      cont1.Add(objA); //objA is local varible that has been defined. 
      cont1.Add(objB); //objB is local varible that has been defined. 
      cont1.Add(objC); //objC is local varible that has been defined. 
      cont1.Add(objD); //objD is local varible that has been defined. 
      cont1.Add(objE); //objE is local varible that has been defined.

      int count = cont1.Count; 

      List<Item> cont2 = GroupingA(cont1, count);

      for (int i = 0; i < cont1.Count; i++)
      {
         Console.Write(cont1[i].Name + " ");//output the item's name.

      }
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("Container 2: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < cont2.Count; i++)
      {
         Console.Write(cont2[i].Name + " ");//output the item's name.
      }
    }
}
```

```
public class GroupItem
{
    public List<Item> GroupingA (List<Item> obj, int count)
    {
        List<Item> temp = new List<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (i == count - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (temp.Count > 0 )
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
                {
                    bool equal = obj[i].EqualFirstPhase(obj[j]);
                    if (equal == true)
                    {
                        if (temp.Exists(element => element == temp[j]))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp.Add(obj[j]);
                            if (temp.Exists(element => element == obj[i]))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                temp.Insert(0, obj[i]);
                            }
                            i--;

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < temp.Count; l++)
                {
                    if (obj[k].Name.Contains(temp[l].Name))
                    {
                        obj.RemoveAt(k);
                        count--;

                    }
                }
                if (obj.Count < count)
                {
                    k = 0;

                }
            }


        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

I want to use `GroupingA` method to regroup the `cont1` into `cont2`. However, there is an error.

> The name 'GroupingA ' does not exist in the current context.

Anyone can help me??? Really weak in OOP, especially naming.

Comment: I suspect you meant for `GroupingA` (and possibly `GroupItem`) to be static. If you redefine `GroupingA` to be: `public static List<Item> GroupingA(List<Item> obj, int count);` and change the original call in your `Main` method to be: `List<Item> cont2 = GroupItem.GroupingA(cont1, count);` it will compile and run. But I'm not too sure if it's your _intent_ or not for them to be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to use :-

```
GroupItem grpItem  = new GroupItem(); 
List<Item> cont2 = grpItem.GroupingA(cont1, count);
```

Reason:-

Your GroupingA method is non-static and defined in the class `GroupingItem`. And you are trying to access it from your Program class as if the method `GroupingA` is a part of that class. For accessing non-static methods from other classes you need to `Instantiate` that class and use that object to get access to the class. In case of static method you can directly access them with the `.` operator on that particular class. ex Class.Method(...)

Comment: Thanks, It works!
Only a simple stuff, but make me headache to ask for helping.

Comment: @kingjia, if this helped you solve your problem, please mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: @kingjia glad it helped. I would recommend you to read more on the OO Concepts. Hanlet, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The line
`List<Item> cont2 = GroupingA(cont1, count);` is being called in the class `Program`.

Without a class name or object identifier that says where a method is located, it will look in the current class, which in your case is `Program`.

You have several choices.

- Make the `GroupingA` method static and replace the line with `List<Item> cont2 = GroupItem.GroupingA(cont1, count);`
- Make an instance of GroupItem and refer to that instead:

  ```
  GroupItem g = new GroupItem();
  List<Item> cont2 = your.GroupingA(cont1, count);
  ```
- Move the method `GroupingA` out of the `GroupItem` class and place it within the `Program` class so your line knows where to find it.

Comment: Both are good answers! But I marked the first one, since it came first. Sorry~